# Ajax post request return empty querydict

Tags: python, ajax, django

i'm trying to send a post request and authenticate a user based on that information. however even though i have checked the result from `$('#sign_in').serialize()` and it returns something like `username=test&password=test` it still returns `<QueryDict: {}>` when i run `print(request.POST)` inside my views.py. What am i doing wrong and why is it not passing the parameters?

**ajax function**

```
function logIn() {
    var username = $('#id_username').val();
    var password = $('#id_password').val();
    console.log($('#sign_in').serialize())
    $('#sign_in_btn').text('Logger ind...');
    $.ajax({
        url: "/account/login/",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: $('#sign_in').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)

        }, error: function (error) {

        }
    });
}
```

**views.py**

```
def login(request):
    print(request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignInForm(data=request.POST)
        response_data = {}
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST.get("username", False)
            password = request.POST.get("password", False)
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            auth_login(request, user)
            if user:
                response_data['success'] = True
                response_data['message'] = 'Brugeren er blevet oprettet!'
        else: #invalid case
            response_data['success'] = False
            response_data['message'] = 'Forkert brugernavn/kodeord. Prøv venligst en anden kombination eller tryk på glemt kodeord!'
            print(form.errors)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type='application/json')
    else:
        form = SignInForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `contentType` to ***application/x-www-form-urlencoded*** instead or leave it blank because its default value is ***application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8***.

> The thing is `.serialize()` returns the content of the form
>   URL-encoded not as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

[lcastillov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4586108/lcastillov) already answered your question, but if you want to send json data to server, here are couple of things you should take care of.

You will get data in `request.data` as you have set contentType to ***application/json***

Also your `data` attribute of $.ajax() function should be in *json* format

```
data: {
   "username": "test",
   "password": "test"
}
```

and now you can easily fetch data in your views

```
request.data["username"]
request.data["password"]
```

> `request.POST` is for form-encoded data having contentType
>   ***application/x-www-form-urlencoded***