# request.POST is empty in django 1.11 gae app in ajax call

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I updated my django google app engine application from 1.2 to 1.11 and do "revelant" steps (python 2.7), such as

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',     
   url(r'^$','froom.views.index', name='index'),
```

to

```
urlpatterns =  [   
   url(r'^$',views.index, name='index'),
```

and start to use django cripsy forms.

while I run 1.2 version and post form, and get request.POST has dict value with posted form values,

however with 1.11 version, request.POST is empty.

```
request.POST = <QueryDict: {}>
```

I double check my ajax calls comes with

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47373090/492258)

My method stays same:

```
def edit_tenant(request, tenant_id=None):
    if (request.method == 'POST'):     
        if tenant_id:
            tenant_id_int = long(tenant_id)
            tenant_org = db.get(db.Key.from_path('Tenant', tenant_id_int))
            form = TenantForm(request.POST, instance = tenant_org, prefix = "edittenant")
```

django settings.py as below:

working version one's:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'),
)
```

none working version one's:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'),
            os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'myapplication'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

What could be issue that upgraded versions request.POST is empty?

Comment: Probably to do with CSRF protection, although I'm surprised you don't get a 403 error.

Comment: I tried with CSRF as well, but not success

Comment: What did you do to try "with CSRF"?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks, I posted how the issue resolved as answer. Thanks again for direction to right point

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolved with "@Daniel Roseman" comments which points to csrf token:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.auth', 
    'myapplication',
    'django_forms_bootstrap',
    'crispy_forms',     
)
```

when I add `'django.contrib.auth',`

and update :

```
  return render_to_response('edit_tenant.html')
```

to

return render(request, 'edit_tenant.html')

It puts

```
 <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='itg3eY4YnesCy6p5enJS19txbMDI49Gf4UUEPQjOkUtyoEDBBO1L8nyborVD9prW' />
```

However I should have add `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` as well:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'gaesessions.DjangoSessionMiddleware',
)
```